# Downloading a 2MB File in PHP

Tags: php, file

I'm writing a function that updates a database file every 30 days. It works great for small files, but for files over 200K or so, it just downloads a partial file. How can I make this work with files up to 2MB?

```
function lsmi_geoip_update() {
    $dir = dirname( __FILE__ );
    $localfilev4 = $dir . '/data/GeoIPv4.dat';
    $localfilev6 = $dir . '/data/GeoIPv6.dat';
    if ( file_exists( $localfilev4 ) ) {
        rename($dir . '/data/GeoIPv4.dat', $dir . '/data/OLD_GeoIPv4.dat');
        $newfilev4 = file_get_contents('http://gdriv.es/geoipupdate/GeoIPv4.dat');
        file_put_contents($dir . '/data/GeoIPv4.dat', $newfilev4);
        // unlink($dir . '/data/OLD_GeoIPv4.dat');
    }
    if ( file_exists( $localfilev6 ) ) {
        rename($dir . '/data/GeoIPv6.dat', $dir . '/data/OLD_GeoIPv6.dat');
        $newfilev6 = file_get_contents('http://gdriv.es/geoipupdate/GeoIPv6.dat');
        file_put_contents($dir . '/data/GeoIPv6.dat', $newfilev6);
        // unlink($dir . '/data/OLD_GeoIPv6.dat');
    }
}
```

Here's the output:

[image]

Comment: Look into php.ini for max size limit

Comment: php.ini is already set above 2M.

Comment: Also look for `post_max_size`

Comment: `post_max_size` is also fine.

Answer (score 1):

you must change the setting in the php.ini upload_max_filesize = 2M
and max_execution_time = X according to your need.

Answer (score 1):

Edit php.ini to allow bigger upload first. Add (or find & edit) `upload_max_filesize = 2M` to your `php.ini`.

If that doesn't work, consider `file_get_contents` (= *downloading*) failing in the first place.
Your connection could be timing out before it can fetch the whole data. Try this.
(Sorry I can't comment everywhere yet that I had to answer on guessing)

```
$ctx = stream_context_create(array( 
    'http' => array( 
        'timeout' => 120 
        ) 
    ) 
); 
file_get_contents("http://gdriv.es/geoipupdate/GeoIPv4.dat", 0, $ctx);
```

Comment: `upload_max_filesize` is already set to over `2M`. I tried the code above but still get the same result. I'll add a screenshot to my question above.

Answer (score 1):

Hosting the files on a different server fixed it.